# AttributeError: 'TimedeltaProperties' object has no attribute 'years' in Pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

In Pandas, why does a `TimedeltaProperties` object have no attribute 'years'?

After all, the `datetime` object has this property.

It seems like a very natural thing for an object that is concerned with time to have. Especially if it already has an hours, seconds, etc attribute.

Is there a workaround so that my column, which is full of values like
`10060 days`,
can be converted to years?  Or better yet, just converted to an integer representation for years?

Comment: Becaluse the number of days in one year is not an exact value.

Comment: A `datetime` does not have a `years` attribute. It has a `year` attribute, because it's simple and mostly well-defined to say that a particular datetime is in 2009. It is not so simple to say how many years long a particular duration is; is a year 365 days? 366? Are we supposed to keep track of when a timedelta starts and ends to make the decision?

Comment: Even where `f["age_diff"] = f["date2"] - f["date1"]`, Pandas isn't smart enough to figure out how many years (in floating point) this is?

Comment: Also note that the reason `TimedeltaProperties` has no such attribute, is because a `pd.Timedelta` or `datetime.timedelta` object (first is subclass of the second) has no such attribute. And this is indeed for the reasons stated above.

Answer (score 15):

`TimedeltaProperties` does not have `year` or `month` attributes because according to TimedeltaProperties [source code](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tseries/common.py) . It is -

> Accessor object for datetimelike properties of the Series values.

But , `months` or `years` have no constant definition.

`1 month` can take on different different number of days, based on the `month` itself, like January -> 31 days , April -> 30 days , etc.

`1 month` can take on different values based on the year as well (in case of February month) , if the year is 2004 , February has 29 days , if the year is 2003 February has 28 days, etc.

Same is the case with `years` , it can take on different values based on which exact year it is, for example - if the year is 2003 , it has 365 days, if the year is 2004 it has 366 days.

Hence, an requirement like - Convert `10060 days` to `years` is not accurate, which `years`?

Like previously stated, the accurate amount of years those no. of days correspond to depend on the actual years those days represent.

Answer (score 6):

This workaround gets you closer.

`round((df["Accident Date"] - df["Iw Date Of Birth"]).dt.days / 365, 1)`

Answer (score 2):

I used **.astype('timedelta64[Y]')** and then **.astype('int')** to get integer years:

```
df['age'] = (pd.Timestamp('now') - df.birthDate).astype('timedelta64[Y]').astype('int')
```

Output:

```
nflId   height  weight  birthDate   collegeName           position  displayName    age
0   2539334 72  190 1990-09-10      Washington              CB  Desmond Trufant    30
1   2539653 70  186 1988-11-01      Southeastern Louisiana  CB  Robert Alford      31
2   2543850 69  186 1991-12-18      Purdue                  SS  Ricardo Allen      28
3   2555162 73  227 1994-11-04      Louisiana State         MLB Deion Jones        25
4   2555255 75  232 1993-07-01      Minnesota               OLB DeVondre Campbell  27
```